# RxJs: Throwing an error doesn't allow .retryWhen when Observable starts with .fromEvent

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an Observable that is initiated by an 'input' event. Whenever I want to throw an error retryWhen it RxJs doesn't allow me to retry the Observable. this seems to specifically happen with .fromEvent.

What I want is to able to throw an error *without* the Observable completing ,catch that and to execute some code like logging or DOM manipulation.

Console gives me `Uncaught TypeError: a.addListener is not a function`
 whenever I try to run the code.

Example code:

```
var userIdInputStr = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document.querySelector('#inputUserID'), 'input')
  .map(U.getTargetValue)
  .map(_ => {
    throw 'Error';
  })
  .retryWhen(e => {
    e.pipe(
      e.tap(console.log('Something went wrong...')),
      e.delay(500)
    );
  })
  .subscribe(v => {
    console.log('Got value, nothing happened.');
  });
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `retryWhen`'s callback.

Comment: When you use `{ ... }` this makes a new closure so if you just want to return `e.pipe()` you need to use `.retryWhen(e => e.pipe(..))` or include the `return` keyword

Comment: I shouldn't post these things at the end of the day... 
However, it still gives me the same error...